# Search block in network stream as quick as possible

Tags: c++, performance, search, stream, header

I want ask the method for searching pattern in network stream.

My current method is to allocate a big cache, put data from socket to cache, when the data size exceed a threshold, then start to search all of sync headers (using KMP algorithm) in cache. It works, but looks somehow cumbersome.

The header is very simple flag such as "0xFFEEBBAA1290".

Is there a trick to check the header as quick as possible in realtime without accumulation? That is while receiving data, check whether the complete data block is arrived just in time.

The data is arriving continuously and no any interval to indicates different data blcok.

I used the circular buffer to check the first header and next header to decide the whole block, but numerous modulo (for circular buffer index) operations slow down the speed drastically. I just used memcmp to find header.

FYI, My prefer language is C/C++.

Hope to get your advice. Any reference link also welcome.

Thank you.

---

Please allow me to add some details about this problem.

The data come from a board which is not in my control.
The device send data from arbitray position from his source and don't follow any rule like when connection established must start with a package the header on the front. And even worse the block length is not fixed, I must get block by checking  2 headers.

In my approach, I try to find first header at begin time, if it not meet, I will drop each byte until the header come. 
On this way at least I can gurantee the first header is at the begin of cache(The cache size is much smaller than KMP approach because I don't want search headers in delay), then continue to receive data and check next header simultaneously.

If found the block, the block data will move to other process, then second header will move to front of cache.
It causes the cache should be re-aligned to accept next data, this is why I used the circular buffer (store data to array) to implement. i.e., just set read and write position, not actually move remain data in cache.

list or vector is tried but not used because of byte chunk operations and performance consideration.

The problem is I have to continuously check the next header ***while data arriving***.

Is there an elegant way to avoid such frequent byte scan?

Or if the speed is reasonable I also can accept the frequent byte scan, but the modulo operation for calculating reading and writing position in circular buffer seems slow down the performance.
I used different profiling tool and all indicate the frequent modulo is performance bottleneck.

Comment: How does this problem actually arise? You should be parsing the entire input stream, so that the next header is automatically immediately after the last parsed message. You shouldn't have to scan for anything.

Comment: I receive the data from front device which don't care my status, it just send data using TCP/IP it generated. I don't know when the data begins, I should just connect the device any time and start to receive, so when I start receiving data, the first data may be a part of data block, only after some bytes passed the actual header I will meet. I don't know how to find header from input stream without scan bytes. And the data block is between 2 headers. The data injecting speed is a bit fast, so I have to process data as quick as possible.

Comment: And only complete block is usable for next process. So I have to ensure the picked blcok must be complete

Comment: I do not understand. The data begins at the beginning of the connection. The device isn't going to start sending a message from its middle. It will start by sending a message header.

Comment: The device actually does, the device send data from arbitray position from his source and don't follow any rule. In my approach, I try to find first header at begin time, if it not meet, I will drop each byte until the header come, on this way at least I can gurantee the first header is at the begin of cache(much smaller than my first approach, find multiple headers in one time), then continue to receive data. The problem is I have to continuously check whether the next header in the cache.

Comment: The device actually does, the device send data from arbitray position from his source and don't follow any rule like when connection established must send a package with header on the front. The device is an development board and not in my control.

Comment: In that case I would *start* along the lines you mention, a large buffer and a KMP or BM search, but once a message is found you should revert to parsing it properly and never having to do the scan again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"as quick as possible in realtime" is already a contradiction. Realtime means as fast as the data arrives; no need to be faster than that. In fact, realtime often is slower than batch processing.

Realtime also requires hard figures on time available and time taken, neither of which are available here.

Your header appears to <8 bytes, which is 1 cache line. KMP or similar algorithms are unlikely to be needed. Checking all bytes in a cache line for `0xFF` is almost certainly faster than checking a single byte against `0xFF, 0xEE, 0xBB, 0xAA, 0x12 or 0x90`.

Now, "numerous modulo (for circular buffer index) operations slow down the speed drastically" is a realistic problem. But that does have a straightforward solution. Make sure that the buffer size is a *compile time constant*, and a *power of two*. `x%(1<<N)` is equal to `x & ((1<<N)-1)`

Comment: Yes, the description of realtime might be wrong. My purpose is to describe the processing speed is slower than data arriving speed, and it's actually happend in my program. The modulo method is very brilliant, I will try it. And I don't really understand "Checking all bytes in a cache line for 0xFF", how to do it? using bitwise "AND"? Could you give me an example?

Comment: @LiJianMing: You don't need to manually check all bytes in a cacheline - the whole cache is automatic. I'm just explaining why I expect a simple search to be faster than a KMP search.

Comment: Thank you Sir, you mean just compare a bunch of bytes with given pattern, like memcmp does? "automatic" is little hard to understand. Anyway I think I almost understand your meaning, don't apply complex algorithm like KMP on this situation, just use general simple search algorithm will be better.

Comment: Okay, I googled "cache line" and I found the cache line is dedicated noun which can hold 64 bytes. I don't know it before. It's very helpful, I will dig into this. If you give me some advice will be very appreciated. Thank you very much1